# How do I Access Specfic Elements of Webpage for Import into Pandas

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this code that scrapes a website for menu information. I have got it working so that it gets the text from this week menu items:

```
#Weekly Breakfast Menu
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://trinity.campusdish.com/Commerce/Catalog/Menus.aspx?LocationId=1031&PeriodId=1471&MenuDate=&Mode=week")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_day=soup.find(id="WebPartManager1_wpMenuDetails")
menu_items=seven_day.find_all(class_="menu-details")
week=menu_items[0]

seven_days = week.find("div",class_="menu-details-week").get_text()
print(seven_days)
```

Currently, it prints the data in a long list that contains the date, meal station, and meal name. I'm stuck because I can't figure out a way to separate these values to make a pandas data frame with these three headers.

I tried this code to access the days of the week and see if it prints but I keep getting this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

My non-working code to print the days looks like this:

```
day = week.find("h2", class_="menu-details-day").get_text()
print(day)
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: do "date", "meal station" and "meal name" have separate tags in the HTML? if yes you can use `soup.<tag here>.get_text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://trinity.campusdish.com/Commerce/Catalog/Menus.aspx?LocationId=1031&PeriodId=1471&MenuDate=&Mode=week")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

menu = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'menu-details-day'})

d = []

for day in menu:
    day_of_week = day.find('h2').text
    stations = day.find_all('div',{'class':'menu-details-station'})

    for station in stations:
        station_type = station.find('h4').text
        foods = station.find_all('div',{'class': 'menu-details-station-item'})
        for food in foods:
            item = food.find('div',{'class':'menu-name'}).text.replace('\n','')
            d.append((day_of_week,station_type,item))

print(pd.DataFrame(d,columns=('Day','Menu','Food')))
```

The output is :

```
     Day                 Menu                              Food
0    Mon              COMFORT                             Grits
1    Mon              COMFORT             Old Fashioned Oatmeal
2    Mon              COMFORT           Hash Brown Potato Patty
3    Mon              COMFORT            Applewood Smoked Bacon
4    Mon              COMFORT                Pork Sausage Patty
5    Mon              COMFORT               Turkey Sausage Link
6    Mon              COMFORT                  Southern Biscuit
7    Mon              COMFORT                     Sausage Gravy
8    Mon              COMFORT          Scrambled Eggs Cage Free
9    Mon              DESSERT                   Blueberry Scone
10   Mon              DESSERT                             Bagel
11   Mon              DESSERT                     Danish Pastry
12   Mon              DESSERT                    English Muffin
13   Mon              DESSERT                Iced Cinnamon Roll
14   Mon              DESSERT                         Croissant
15   Mon              DESSERT                       White Bread
16   Mon              DESSERT                 Whole Wheat Bread
17   Mon              DESSERT              Strawberry Preserves
18   Mon              DESSERT                     Peanut Butter
19   Mon              DESSERT                Bacon Cream Cheese
20   Mon              DESSERT              Whipped Cream Cheese
21   Mon              DESSERT                           Nutella
22   Mon              DESSERT                    Whipped Butter
23   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                      Bacon Pieces
24   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL          Diced Pork Sausage Patty
25   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                      Diced Turkey
26   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                               Egg
27   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                        Egg Whites
28   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL           Shredded Cheddar Cheese
29   Mon  INTERNATIONAL GRILL               Shredded Mozzarella
..   ...                  ...                               ...
235  Sun              DESSERT                   Blueberry Scone
236  Sun              DESSERT                             Bagel
237  Sun              DESSERT                     Danish Pastry
238  Sun              DESSERT                    English Muffin
239  Sun              DESSERT                Iced Cinnamon Roll
240  Sun              DESSERT                         Croissant
241  Sun              DESSERT                       White Bread
242  Sun              DESSERT                 Whole Wheat Bread
243  Sun              DESSERT                       Grape Jelly
244  Sun              DESSERT                     Peanut Butter
245  Sun              DESSERT                Pesto Cream Cheese
246  Sun              DESSERT              Whipped Cream Cheese
247  Sun              DESSERT                           Nutella
248  Sun              DESSERT                    Whipped Butter
249  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                      Bacon Pieces
250  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL          Diced Pork Sausage Patty
251  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                               Egg
252  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                        Egg Whites
253  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL           Shredded Cheddar Cheese
254  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL               Shredded Mozzarella
255  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL              Turkey Sausage Patty
256  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                      Baby Spinach
257  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                    Diced Tomatoes
258  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                 Sauteed Mushrooms
259  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL                    Sauteed Onions
260  Sun  INTERNATIONAL GRILL       Sauteed Red & Green Peppers
261  Sun                PIZZA  Bacon & Grilled Potato Flatbread
262  Sun                PIZZA              Classic Cheese Pizza
263  Sun                PIZZA                  Margherita Pizza
264  Sun                PIZZA                   Pepperoni Pizza
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!